# Can I queue a delete on a file?

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have data in memory that represents an image. I want to open the image in the default program to open images. Therefore, I create a temporary file, write the data to it, and then open the file with the default application. Currently, I am using Qt to do the last step via `QDesktopServices::openUrl ( const QUrl & url )`. The problem is that I now have this random file lying around on disk. Is there a way that I can queue a delete on the file so that after the app closes it gets deleted?

As far as OS is concerned, I'd prefer a os independent solution, but I am guessing that none probably exists. Therefore, if you could link to/post how to do it in linux/osx/windows, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Your program need to be active during the default application show the file? If not, just wait for the external program to end and delete the file.

Comment: @Babblo I thought about that, the problem is that I have no clue what application was used to open the file. Furthermore, even if I knew what the name of the application was, there might be more than one instance and I wouldnt know which it was.

Comment: I don't know much about QT, but I'm pretty sure that there will be some way to launch a external process and wait until it's done.

Comment: On Posix, try `mkstemp`.

Comment: @chacham15 I've done this a long time ago so the details are extremely blurry, but you can definitely open a document and wait for the associated process to stop. IIRC I did this using WinAPI `ShellExecuteEx` at the time but I'd be very surprised if other OSes didn't provide the same service. However I'm not sure if Qt provides the corresponding cross-platform abstraction so you might have to write platform dependent code (`#ifdef`s).

Answer (score 1):

On a POSIX system (any Unix or Linux machine), there's a nice trick you can take advantage of:  you can remove the directory entry for the file with `unlink` after opening the file. As long as you keep an open filehandle on the file, it will not be removed, but once you've closed it, the filesystem will automatically reclaim the storage.